# Existence of divisor in the Jacobian of smooth curve of genus two whose intersection with theta divisor is 1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, intersection-theory

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $2$ and $J$ denotes the Jacobian of $C$. Let $\theta$ be the image of $C$ under the abel Jacobi map.
Is there exist a divisor $D$ in $J$ such that $D.\theta=1$?

Is it true that the condition $D.\theta=1$ implies that $J $ biregular to $ D\times \theta$?

Comment: Assuming $g(C)>1$, you can not have $J=D\times \theta$, because an abelian variety (such as $J$) does not dominate any curve of genus at least two.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I have modified  question now for genus $2$ case for simplicity.

Comment: There can be no isomorphism $J = D\times \theta$. If there is, then there would be a surjective morphism $J\to \theta$, but $\theta \cong C$, so $J$ would dominate the genus two curve $C$. That is impossible.

Comment: Is it true that the condition $D.\theta=1$ implies that $J $ biregular to $ D\times \theta$?

Comment: Please read Ariyan's answer. If an abelian surface is isomorphic to a product, both factors are elliptic curves.

Comment: @abx my original question is about existence of $D$ such that $D.\theta=1$. To check that I was trying to prove that this condition implies that $J\cong D\times \theta$. Ariyan's answer work after that.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand your question now:  you want your $D$ to be *effective*, hence irreducible since $\theta $ is ample. Now the index theorem $(D\cdot \theta )^2\geq D^2\cdot\theta ^2\ $ implies $D^2=0$, hence $D$ must be a smooth elliptic curve. Consider the quotient map $p:J\rightarrow J/D$. The condition $D\cdot \theta=1 $ means that the restriction of $p$ to $\theta $ is one-to-one, which is impossible since $g(\theta )=2$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there exist any map from $J\to D\times \theta$? Just by using the fact $D.\theta=1$, where $D$ is effective divisor. I am very sorry if I am asking very silly question.

Comment: No, there is no nontrivial map from an abelian variety to a curve of genus $\geq 2$ (as Aryan said already).